# keep timer time continue after refresh jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

code:

```
<div class="readTiming">
    <time>00:00:00</time><br/>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="readTime" id="readTime">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var p = document.getElementsByClassName('readTiming')[0],
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;
    function add() {
        seconds++;
        if (seconds >= 60) {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes++;
            if (minutes >= 60) {
                minutes = 0;
                hours++;
            }
        }
        p.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);
        timer();
        localStorage.setItem("timeStore", p.textContent);
        getElementsByClassName('readTiming').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("timeStore");
        $("#readTime").val(p.textContent);
    }
    function timer() {
        t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
    }
    timer();
</script>
```

In this code I have a timer. Now, I want if a user refresh page then it will not change and timer time will me continue and if user press on browser back button then it will save the out time. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried using localStorage?

Comment: you need use any kind of storage like cookie, localStorage, because the web page is stateless in basic

Comment: what problem is occurring with your current code, specifically? You haven't explained. Please describe the exact issue, so we can focus on that. (Hint: "not working" is **not** an adequate description...please do some debugging and then report the results)

Comment: After using localstorage it still start from 1 sec

Comment: @navi that's just a symptom report. Please do some debugging and narrow down the problem. Do you understand how to debug JavaScript programs? If not, now would be a great time to start learning.

Comment: P.S here's a hint: every time you run the script, you are setting the value into the localstorage, but you are not checking first whether a value already exists! So you always overwrite the previous value. If you had stepped through the code with a debugger and looked at the values of your variables, and considered the logic of the individual steps in your code, you might have noticed this. You need some extra code (before you set the timer) to check if a value already exists in localstorage, and if so, set the value in the "readTiming" element to that, before you start anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No doubt by now you have managed to get your code working - on the off-chance that you do not then perhaps this might be of interest. It uses, as the others, `localStorage` to maintain the current count of elapsed seconds since the script began. The anonymous self executing functions act like `setInterval` or a recursive `setTimeout` - on each iteration the elapsed time is displayed according to the format laid out in the `format` function and the new value saved to storage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Timer with page refresh</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class='readTiming'>
            <time>00:00:00</time>
        </div>

        <script>
            (function(){

                function format( time ){ 
                    var h = ~~( time / 3600 );
                    var m = ~~( ( time % 3600 ) / 60 );
                    var s = time % 60;
                    return pad( h ) + ':' + pad( m ) + ':' + pad( s );
                }
                function pad( i ){ return ( parseInt( i ) < 10 ) ? '0' + parseInt( i ) : parseInt( i ) }

                const TIMERNAME='continuous_timer';



                (function(){
                    if( !localStorage.getItem( TIMERNAME ) )localStorage.setItem( TIMERNAME, 0 );

                    var _time=parseInt( localStorage.getItem( TIMERNAME ) );
                        _time++;

                    localStorage.setItem( TIMERNAME, _time );

                    document.querySelector('.readTiming time').textContent = format( _time );
                    setTimeout( arguments.callee, 1000 );
                })()
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifically to your code, it seems that you are always setting your `localstorage` value. You would have to check if the value from the local storage exists before you populate it. This is achieved by using the `getItem` method in the WebStorage specification, which explicitly returns `null` if the item does not exist. As per the specs, if the given key does not exist in the list associated with the object then this method must return null.

I have made the use of `session storage` functionality which is similar to local storage- the difference being that session storage life cycle is that of a session in a browser. The value is lost as soon as you close the browser. I have used the `getitem`, `setitem` and `remvoveitem` methods of session storage to achieve the functionality. Hope this helps.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var p = document.getElementsByClassName('readTiming')[0],
            seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
            t;
        function add() {
            if (sessionStorage.getItem("timeStoreSeconds")) {
                seconds = sessionStorage.getItem("timeStoreSeconds");
            }
            if (sessionStorage.getItem("timeStoreMinutes")) {
                minutes = sessionStorage.getItem("timeStoreMinutes");
            }
            if (sessionStorage.getItem("timeStoreHours")) {
                hours = sessionStorage.getItem("timeStoreHours");
            }
            seconds++;
            sessionStorage.setItem("timeStoreSeconds", seconds);
            if (seconds >= 60) {
                seconds = 0;
                sessionStorage.removeItem("timeStoreSeconds");
                minutes++;
                sessionStorage.setItem("timeStoreMinutes", minutes);
                if (minutes >= 60) {
                    minutes = 0;
                    sessionStorage.removeItem("timeStoreMinutes")
                    hours++;
                    sessionStorage.setItem("timeStoreHours", hours);
                }
            }
            p.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);
            timer();
            //localStorage.setItem("timeStore", p.textContent);
            //getElementsByClassName('readTiming').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("timeStore");
            $("#readTime").val(p.textContent);
        }
        function timer() {
            t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
        }
        timer();
    </script>
```

Comment: still when I refresh page it start from 1sec

Comment: @navi Updated the answer as required.